# I have to determine if the function is differentiable in (0,0)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Consider the function :
$$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} , (x,y) \mapsto
  \begin{cases}
{x^2y^2\cos}  
 \frac{1}{x^2y^2}       & \text{for } xy \neq 0
  \end{cases} $$

how can I apply the inequality of Cauchy-Schwarz to this function to show that the function limit tends to zero for (x, y) that tends to (0,0) ?

Comment: Why would you need to? The cosine function is bounded (between $\pm1$), so your function is always between $\pm x^2y^2$

Comment: What about the squeeze theorem? See @Andrei comment.

Comment: Okkay guys thank you for the comments !!

Comment: Limits don't tend to anything. The function might.